# CardView OnClick is called twice

Tags: android, android-layout, android-cardview

I'm using CardView with this attribute `android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"`

and I have set onClickListener.

when I click the card twice very fast The onClick method is called twice.(I think it is because of the ripple effect)
How can I prevent that?

thank you

Comment: What kind of question is this? if you have setup clicklistener and clicking twice obviously it will get called twice. Though if you want to prevent that you can keep counter of clicked and upon reaching more than 1 return from onClick() method. Please enlighten me if i am missing anything

Comment: I have set my event to open a new activity but when I click one more time before the ripple animation is finished another activity is created and it's a bug for my app

Comment: Can you please paste code here ?

Comment: @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ProductGroupDetailActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra(ProductGroupDetailActivity.EXTRA_PRODUCT_GROUP_NUMBER, (Integer) view.getTag(R.id.tag_productGroupNumber));
                        MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
                    }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not because of ripple effect as you click twice fastly then click event will called twice, so to prevent this try below code

```
private long mLastClickTime = 0;


card_view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        // double-click prevention, using threshold of 1500 ms(1.5 second)
        if (SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - mLastClickTime < 1500){
            return;
        }
        mLastClickTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();

        // do your code here

    }
});
```

Comment: @M.Kasaei, Welcome mate:)

Comment: But one more question, Why app closes when I double click the view?

Comment: @M.Kasaei, is it crashing or just app close ?

Comment: just closing the app then when I open that again continues from the point I want

Comment: @M.Kasaei, Please check the code , there might be part which make it happens to close the app, please post the inside code of cardview click event.

Comment: the code inside the onClick event==>Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ProductGroupDetailActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra(ProductGroupDetailActivity.EXTRA_PRODUCT_GROUP_NUMBER, (Integer) view.getTag(R.id.tag_productGroupNumber));
                        MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent);

Comment: @M.Kasaei, replace your intent code with just toast msg and check if it's working properly, if yes then check code in productgroupdetialactivity class.... Or your above intent code....

Comment: It works on toast and Logcat but not for activity I don't understand why? Do you have any Idea?(even not working for simple activity)

Comment: @M.Kasaei, please post another question for this, and put the code of intent as well as code of activty which you are going to open through intent, so that we can solve it.

Comment: this is my [qustion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51805260/activity-closes-when-double-click-a-cardview-to-open)

Comment: @M.Kasaei, i have just commented in your above question please check