# Activity closes when double click a CardView to open

Tags: android, android-activity

I have MainActivity which has a cardView inside a recyclerView and I want to double click on the card view to open the SecondActivity But when I touch the cardView twice very quickly I see that the app completely closes and I see android home screen and apps screen But when I touch the app launcher icon again I see the second activity.
(I have handled twice click with a boolean flag)

MyCode:

recyclerView onClick event:

```
 @Override
                public void onClick(final View view) {
                    if (AppActivity.isResponding()) {
                        Log.i("MainActivity", "onClick: applied");
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ProductGroupDetailActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra(ProductGroupDetailActivity.EXTRA_PRODUCT_GROUP_NUMBER, (Integer) view.getTag(R.id.tag_productGroupNumber));
                        MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
                        AppActivity.setResponding(false);
                    }
                }
```

SecondActivity:

```
   @Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    responding = true;
}
```

what's the problem?

thank you

Comment: Can you provide your log file. It's will be helpful

Comment: in resume and pause of every activity I change the flag(as I checked with logcat flag algorithm was OK) my problem is in opening a new activity

Comment: This seems to be crash, so please post your log here

Comment: No it is not crash. and nothing is written in the logcat

Comment: @M.Kasaei, Please comment `AppActivity.setResponding(false);` and check if its still occuring.

Comment: it does not work. some times I see two activities are created and sometimes app closes with no crash and log error but when I click the launcher icon app continues correctly from the destination activity

Comment: The correct answer is here. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51907827/activity-stops-unexpectedly-without-crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51907827/activity-stops-unexpectedly-without-crash)