# Activity stops unexpectedly without crash

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a RecyclerView of CardViews.
I try to open a new Activity whenever one of the items of RecyclerView is clicked.
then I saw if the user clicks the card two times very quickly the activity is opening twice , so I added a boolean called responding to ignore the second touch.

but now I faced another bug. when I click the card twice quickly the app closes and I see my phone background and when I click the launcher icon again I see the second activity that I was going to see.

and here is my Logcat when I click the card twice fast.

logcat:

```
onPause: MainActivity
onCreate: ProductGroupDetailActivity
onStart: ProductGroupDetailActivity
onResume: ProductGroupDetailActivity
onPause: ProductGroupDetailActivity
onStop: MainActivity
onStop: ProductGroupDetailActivity
```

AppActivity (I have extended all my activities from this class):

```
package project.activities;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;

import project.G;

public abstract class AppActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public static final int LOADING_DELAY = 500;

private static boolean responding = true;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.i(G.LOG_TAG, "onCreate: " + this.getClass().getSimpleName());
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Log.i(G.LOG_TAG, "onStart: " + this.getClass().getSimpleName());
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Log.i(G.LOG_TAG, "onResume: " + this.getClass().getSimpleName());
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    Log.i(G.LOG_TAG, "onPause: " + this.getClass().getSimpleName());
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    Log.i(G.LOG_TAG, "onStop: " + this.getClass().getSimpleName());
}

@Override
protected void onRestart() {
    super.onRestart();
    Log.i(G.LOG_TAG, "onRestart: " + this.getClass().getSimpleName());
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.i(G.LOG_TAG, "onDestroy: " + this.getClass().getSimpleName());
}

public static boolean isResponding() {
    return responding;
}

public static void disableResponding() {
    responding = false;
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            responding = true;
        }
    }, LOADING_DELAY);
 }
}
```

and here is my adapter for RecyclerView:

```
package project.adapters;

import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.company.app.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import project.helpers.FileHelper;
import project.structure.data.ProductsGroup;

public class GroupProductsRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<GroupProductsRecyclerAdapter.Holder> {

    private ArrayList<ProductsGroup> productsGroups;
    private View.OnClickListener onClickListener;

    public GroupProductsRecyclerAdapter(ArrayList<ProductsGroup> productsGroups, View.OnClickListener onClickListener) {
        this.productsGroups = productsGroups;
        this.onClickListener = onClickListener;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Holder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
        return new Holder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final Holder holder, int position) {
        if (productsGroups.get(position).getImage() != null && productsGroups.get(position).getImage().length() > 0) {
            holder.imgItem.setImageBitmap(FileHelper.getImage(productsGroups.get(position).getImage()));
        }
        holder.txtItem.setText(productsGroups.get(position).getName());
        holder.root.setTag(R.id.tag_productGroupNumber, productsGroups.get(position).getNumber());
        holder.root.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return productsGroups.size();
    }

    static class Holder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        ViewGroup root;
        TextView txtItem;
        ImageView imgItem;

        Holder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            txtItem = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtItem);
            imgItem = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgItem);
            root = (ViewGroup) itemView;
        }
    }
}
```

and finally adapter initializing:

```
GroupProductsRecyclerAdapter gpAdapter = new GroupProductsRecyclerAdapter(G.data.getDefaultLanguage().getProductsGroups(), new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(final View view) {
                        if (AppActivity.isResponding()) {
                            AppActivity.disableResponding();
                            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ProductGroupDetailActivity.class);
                            intent.putExtra(ProductGroupDetailActivity.EXTRA_PRODUCT_GROUP_NUMBER, (Integer) view.getTag(R.id.tag_productGroupNumber));
                            MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    }
                });
                recycler.setAdapter(gpAdapter);
```

Here is the Logcat

```
    08-18 15:41:35.703 14262-14262/? E/adbd: recv: OPEN 000000f7 00000000 0015:73 68 65 6C 6C 3A 6C 6F 67 63 61 74 20 2D 76 20 6C 6F 6E 67 00 
    service_to_fd: shell:logcat -v long

    --------- beginning of system
08-18 15:41:36.315 24460-24460/? W/Notification: Use of stream types is deprecated for operations other than volume control
    See the documentation of setSound() for what to use instead with android.media.AudioAttributes to qualify your playback use case
08-18 15:41:36.363 7191-7191/? E/CatchNotificationsService: Invalid notification data
08-18 15:41:37.325 24460-24460/? W/Notification: Use of stream types is deprecated for operations other than volume control
    See the documentation of setSound() for what to use instead with android.media.AudioAttributes to qualify your playback use case
08-18 15:41:37.333 14644-14644/? W/ContextImpl: Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user: android.app.ContextImpl.sendBroadcast:956 android.content.ContextWrapper.sendBroadcast:442 com.samsung.android.sm.widgetapp.SMWidgetService.a:66 com.samsung.android.sm.widgetapp.SMWidgetService.b:17 com.samsung.android.sm.widgetapp.d.handleMessage:31 
08-18 15:41:37.368 30894-30894/? W/SearchServiceClient: Starting with NO_SESSION handoverId is deprecated. Just don't. You will break.
08-18 15:41:37.385 7191-7191/? E/CatchNotificationsService: Invalid notification data
08-18 15:41:37.394 30894-30894/? W/SessionLifecycleManager: Handover failed. Creating new session controller.
08-18 15:41:37.404 30894-30894/? E/PBSessionCacheImpl: sessionId[135874783492680391] not persisted.
08-18 15:41:37.445 6335-6765/? E/ApplicationPackageManager: checkSettingsForIconTray value : 0
    checkSettingsForIconTray value : 0
08-18 15:41:37.459 5024-7390/? W/StorageManager: getStorageLowBytes lowPercent : 5, lowBytes : 1327564390, maxLowBytes : 524288000
08-18 15:41:37.478 10416-10416/? W/DeviceHAL: Device 0xf20ca500 open_input_stream: Invalid argument
08-18 15:41:37.500 10416-16755/? W/audio_hw_primary: start_input_stream echoReference effect is not supported.
08-18 15:41:37.593 30894-15920/? W/SpeechLevelGenerator: Really low audio levels detected. The audio input may have issues.
08-18 15:41:37.628 6407-6407/? E/SchedPolicy: add_tid_to_cgroup failed; fd=-1
08-18 15:41:37.634 16756-16756/? E//system/bin/webview_zygote32: failed to make and chown /acct/uid_99306: Permission denied
08-18 15:41:37.635 16756-16756/? E/Zygote: createProcessGroup(99306, 0) failed: Permission denied
08-18 15:41:37.635 16756-16756/? E/libpersona: Couldn't open the File - /data/system/users/0.xml - Permission denied
08-18 15:41:37.635 16756-16756/? W/SELinux: SELinux selinux_android_compute_policy_index : Policy Index[2],  Con:u:r:webview_zygote:s0 RAM:SEPF_SM-G935F_8.0.0_0011, [-1 -1 -1 -1 0 1]
08-18 15:41:37.722 16770-16770/? E/asset: setgid: Operation not permitted
08-18 15:41:37.803 10416-10416/? E/audio_hw_primary: adev_close_input_stream, set jack_in to null
08-18 15:41:37.889 16756-16756/? E/Typeface: Error mapping font file /system/fonts/SamsungSans-Num3L.ttf
08-18 15:41:37.889 16756-16756/? E/Minikin: Could not get cmap table size!
08-18 15:41:37.889 16756-16756/? E/Typeface: Unable to load Family: samsung-sans-num3L:null
    Error mapping font file /system/fonts/SamsungSans-Num3T.ttf
08-18 15:41:37.889 16756-16756/? E/Minikin: Could not get cmap table size!
08-18 15:41:37.889 16756-16756/? E/Typeface: Unable to load Family: samsung-sans-num3T:null
    Error mapping font file /system/fonts/SamsungSans-Num4L.ttf
08-18 15:41:37.889 16756-16756/? E/Minikin: Could not get cmap table size!
08-18 15:41:37.889 16756-16756/? E/Typeface: Unable to load Family: samsung-sans-num4L:null
    Error mapping font file /system/fonts/SamsungSans-Num4T.ttf
08-18 15:41:37.889 16756-16756/? E/Minikin: Could not get cmap table size!
08-18 15:41:37.889 16756-16756/? E/Typeface: Unable to load Family: samsung-sans-num4T:null
    Error mapping font file /system/fonts/SamsungSans-Num35.ttf
08-18 15:41:37.889 16756-16756/? E/Minikin: Could not get cmap table size!
08-18 15:41:37.889 16756-16756/? E/Typeface: Unable to load Family: samsung-sans-num35:null
08-18 15:41:37.890 16756-16756/? E/Typeface: Error mapping font file /system/fonts/SamsungSans-Num45.ttf
08-18 15:41:37.890 16756-16756/? E/Minikin: Could not get cmap table size!
08-18 15:41:37.890 16756-16756/? E/Typeface: Unable to load Family: samsung-sans-num45:null
    Error mapping font file /system/fonts/SamsungSans-Num3Lv.ttf
08-18 15:41:37.890 16756-16756/? E/Minikin: Could not get cmap table size!
08-18 15:41:37.890 16756-16756/? E/Typeface: Unable to load Family: samsung-sans-num3LV:null
    Error mapping font file /system/fonts/SamsungSans-Num3R.ttf
08-18 15:41:37.890 16756-16756/? E/Minikin: Could not get cmap table size!
08-18 15:41:37.890 16756-16756/? E/Typeface: Unable to load Family: samsung-sans-num3R:null
    Error mapping font file /system/fonts/SamsungSans-Num4Tv.ttf
08-18 15:41:37.890 16756-16756/? E/Minikin: Could not get cmap table size!
08-18 15:41:37.890 16756-16756/? E/Typeface: Unable to load Family: samsung-sans-num4Tv:null
    Error mapping font file /system/fonts/SamsungSans-Num4Lv.ttf
08-18 15:41:37.890 16756-16756/? E/Minikin: Could not get cmap table size!
08-18 15:41:37.890 16756-16756/? E/Typeface: Unable to load Family: samsung-sans-num4Lv:null
08-18 15:41:37.912 30894-30894/? W/SearchServiceCore: Abort, client detached.
08-18 15:41:38.332 24460-24460/? W/Notification: Use of stream types is deprecated for operations other than volume control See the documentation of setSound() for what to use instead with android.media.AudioAttributes to qualify your playback use case
08-18 15:41:38.368 7191-7191/? E/CatchNotificationsService: Invalid notification data
08-18 15:41:38.462 5024-5038/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
08-18 15:41:38.462 5024-5038/? W/android.os.Debug: failed to get memory consumption info: -1
08-18 15:41:38.470 30894-30894/? W/SearchServiceCore: Abort, client detached.
08-18 15:41:38.490 5024-5038/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
```

**I really got stuck and I don't know why the activity closes?**

thank you every one for reading.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the crash log in the logcat?

Comment: No crash is logged

Comment: I'm a bit sceptical about your boolean, did the issue happen after you put it?

Comment: Set "no filters" instead of "selected application only" then set log level to ERROR instead of DEBUG in logcat

Comment: I had the problem before adding the boolean too.

Comment: @EpicandaForce It does not show sth special

Comment: Show us that "something not special"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of trying and research I found the problem

when I commented this line of code in my app style my problem solved.

```
<item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
```

but I dont know why?

Comment: Hey @M.Kasaei ,  It is not working in my app. Can you please give the solution you tried?

Comment: In my use case deletion of the above code helped me.

may be your problem is sth else

Answer (score 0):

if anyone has this issue on android 6.x with the gms(google play services) libraries, i created an issue on google, [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/123022774)

Answer (score 0):

Add below property to your activity in AndroidManifest.xml

android:launchMode = "singleTop"

**Example**

```
 <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode = "singleTop"/>
```